# what is prototype vector of a phrase in the training set

Tags: machine-learning, wikipedia

I am trying to implement an approaches following [a paper](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~bast/papers/ester.pdf) to disambiguate an entity. The process consists of 2 steps, a training phase and disambiguation phase. I would like to ask about training phase, I do not quite understand how the way to get prototype vectors as this paragraph explained:

> In the training phase, we compute, for each word or phrase that is linked at least 10 times to a particular entity, what we called a prototype vector: this is a tf.idf-weighted, normalized list of all terms which occur in one of the neighbourhoods (we consider 10 words to the left and right) of the respective links. Note that one and the same word or phrase can have several such prototype vectors, one for each entity linked from some occurrence of that word or phrase in the collection.

They have used the approach for wikipedia and use the links from wikipedia as training set.

Could someone help me to give an example of the prototype vector as explained there,please?  I am beginner in this field.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sketch of what the prototype vector is about:

The first thing to note is that a word in wikipedia can be hyperlink to a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity) page (which we will call an *entity*). *This [entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_class) is related in some way to the word yet the same word could link to different entities.*

#### "for each word or phrase that is linked at least 10 times to a particular entity"

Across wikipedia, we count the number of times that `word_A` links to `entity_B`, if it's over 10, we continue (writing down where the entities they link from):

```
[(wordA, entityA1), (wordA, entityA2),...]
```

*Here `wordA` occurs in `entityA1` where it links to `entityB`, etc.*

#### "list of all terms which occur in one of the neighbourhoods of the respective links"

In `entityA1`, `wordA` has ten words to it's left and right (we show only 4 either side):

```
are developed and the entity relationships between these data
                      wordA
                      link # (to entityB)

['are', 'developed, 'and', 'the', 'relationships', 'between', 'these', 'data']
```

Each pair `(wordA, entityAi)` gives us such a list, concatenate them.

#### "tf.idf-weighted, normalized list"

Basically, [tf.idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) means you should give common words less "weight" than less-common words. For example, `'and'` and `'the'` are very common words so we give them less *meaning* (to their being next to `'entity'`) than `'relationships'` or `'between'`.

Normalise, means we should (essentially) count the number of times a word occurs (the more it occurs the more associated we think it is to `wordA`. Then multiply this count by the weight to get some score with which to sort the list... Putting the most-frequent least-common words at the top.

#### "Note that one and the same word or phrase can have several such prototype vectors"

This has been not only dependant on `wordA` but also `entityB`, you could think of it as a mapping.

```
(wordA, entityB) -> tf.idf-weighted, normalized list (as described above)
(wordA, entityB2) -> a different tf.idf-weighted, normalized list
```

*This is making the point that links to [cats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats) from the word `'cat'` are less likely to have the neighbour `'batman'`, than links to [cat woman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_woman).*

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation and fixing my question format. I would like to ask more for the next step related with your question but it is too long so I post it as answer. I do not know it is allowed or I need to make a new title for it? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: No worris, it was an interesting paper. But perhaps you should post it as a new (different) question?