# Creating Prototype Vector for comparison

Tags: python, vector, machine-learning, scikit-learn, similarity

I am trying to implement an approach following a paper which compares the content vectors of words to a prototype vector, which is representative of the entire class/cluster/type/etc. In the first step, a prototype vector is calculated and I do not quite understand how the way to acquire prototype vectors.

I referred to here to the discussion of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621341/what-is-prototype-vector-of-a-phrase-in-the-training-set): However, this post seems to answer what the prototype vector is *theoretically*, while I need to find a *practical* solution to implement.

Is there an implementation in Python // Sci-kit learn that can realize the function of

A. defining/indicate a priori or induce from training instances a prototype vector 
B. then input feature vectors to be compared for similarity against the prototype vector from A.?

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: The answer you received on your other question pretty much summarizes what you need to do. If you're having trouble with some *specific detail* of the implementation, feel free to ask, but as it stands, this amounts to asking 'please implement this for me', so I doubt you'll get an answer

Comment: Actually, I was referring to a specific function // implementation available online that perhaps I have not been able to find and someone in the community is aware of ( for instance a software, a tool implementation) and wants to spread or share the information.

Comment: I see. Since this is a technique used in a specific paper, I don't think there'll be an exact match, but maybe someone can find something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Nearest Centroid Classifier:
http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-centroid-classifier

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked out the Nearest Centroid Classifier and it does seem to offer some very interesting possibilities. However, it seems like it generates its own prototype based on the vectors/matrix provided, rather than permitting the definition of the prototype and then feeding it unseen vectors for comparison. However, I have come across the following (although JAVA): http://wekax.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/wekaUT/weka/classifiers/misc/PrototypeMetric.java Is there something like this that exists for Python (Scikit) ?

Comment: What you describe can be implemented in one or two lines of numpy. Learn numpy, it is really worth it.