# Formulae of Cosine Distance?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

1) I am using the following for measuring the cosine distance between two vectors (let's say A and B).

Lets assume we have two vectors for e.g vector A and vector B,

cosine distance between A & B = (dot(A, B) / (Magnitude (A) * Magnitude (B)))

is this formula right ? if not than kindly suggest me the right formulae ?

2) Is K-NN always better in accuracy than Rocchio or there are some situations when Rocchio performs better than K-NN ? K-NN looks like an enhancement of Rocchio and theoretical concepts suggests that K-NN will perform much better than Rocchio but i am finding vice versa in practical implementation in which Rocchio is performing much better than K-NN ?

Comment: You've correctly defined the cosine of the angle between two vectors, but this is not a "distance": it's largest when the vectors are closest (in the same direction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Cosine distance is one of the similarity measures. Others may include the Euclidean distance or weighted Euclidean distance. You implementation is correct.

(2) The main difference between KNN and Rocchio is there is no training in the former, but prototype vectors are generated during training process in the latter. During test process, all the training instances are used in KNN, but only the [prototype vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621341/what-is-prototype-vector-of-a-phrase-in-the-training-set) are used in Rocchio (usually one vector per class). So the Rocchio is more efficient in both training and test. However it lacks sufficient theoretical validity to demonstrate Rocchio's stability and robustness. And it is shown that Rocchio does not work well if the categories are not linear separable.

Comment: Thanx @lennon310, i have done my own implementation for Rocchio as its not available in weka. I have a data sets of News Articles (1600 for training) & 400 (testing). The rocchio implementation gives me accuracy of 82% whereas when i use the weka implementation for K-nn with 10 & 5 neighbors the result was disappointing for the same data sets (approx 64%). I have read in some articles that Rocchio is efficient but K-nn is more accurate which made me think my implementation has a left in bug which makes accuracy higher. Do you think of any reason like this ?

Comment: Thank you Kashif. I would suggest you shuffle the data and try cross-validation several times, averaging the accuracy to make a better evaluation. In most cases KNN is expected a higher accuracy than Rocchio, but Rocchio may be better tolerate to the noise